# unity-control-center has unmet dependencies after kernel update 4.4.0-47 generic

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg, dependencies

I am trying to resolve some broken packages or unmet dependencies for the package `libgl1-mesa-dev`, but I have not been able to do so. There is some 'red minus' sign showing on the taskbar since I had the kernel update to version 4.4 . The error which I'm getting while installing the package `libgl1-mesa-dev` is as shown below:-

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is       not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I have tried all of the methods including purging the ppa and selecting the `Show Updates` from the minus on the taskbar but it shows some other error like `Package dependencies can't be resolved` and

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are 
missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between 
software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
```

Running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` gives the following :-

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Failed
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: mesa-common-dev (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.6)
ros-indigo-turtlebot-bringup : Depends: ros-indigo-freenect-launch but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Internal error, Upgrade broke stuff
```

`sudo apt-get remove libgl1-mesa-dev` gives the result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcl-1.7-all-dev : Depends: libpcl-apps-1.7-dev but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libpcl-outofcore-1.7-dev but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libpcl-people-1.7-dev but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev but it is not going to be installed
libpcl-io-1.7-dev : Depends: libvtk5-dev but it is not going to be installed
ros-indigo-turtlebot-bringup : Depends: ros-indigo-freenect-launch but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Nothing seems to work, I really need some help with this.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: the ubuntu version is 14.04

Comment: Could you add output of `apt-cache policy unity-control-center libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7 libgl1-mesa-dev mesa-common-dev ros-indigo-turtlebot-bringup ros-indigo-freenect-launch libcheese-gtk23:i386 libcheese7:i386 libgl1-mesa-dev:i386 mesa-common-dev:i386 ros-indigo-turtlebot-bringup:i386 ros-indigo-freenect-launch:i386`  you may post it to paste.ubuntu.com as it's too long

Comment: @user.dz The link is http://paste.ubuntu.com/23490730/

Comment: @MohitRai , open `software-properties-gtk`, disable this ppa http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu , run `sudo apt-get update` then try again

Comment: hey I did some other workaround, I installed synaptic manager and marked the libgl1-mesa-dev for complete removal and then clicked on apply. What it did was it installed some of the unmet dependencies for the package and then completely removed it, the issue is gone and the  big red minus on the taskbar is completely gone which means the dependencies are solved. Thanks a lot guys for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing around with the terminal, I randomly came out with a solution, it is as follows :-

Install Synaptic Package Manager

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Now go to the Synaptic package manager through the start or by typing `sudo synaptic` on the terminal

Next, search for the package with unmet dependencies (in my case `libgl1-mesa-dev`).

Mark the package for `complete removal`

Click `Apply` on the top

Synaptic will first resolve the unmet dependencies and then it will completely remove the package, you can install it again later.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Same error when i install `Qt Creator` on `ubuntu 14.04.1`, found a solution on in [Unmet dependencies for libcheese-gtk23 and libcheese7 on 14.04.2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1428972).

```
sudo apt-get install libglew-dev libcheese7 libcheese-gtk23 libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libcogl15 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-0
```

fixed it for me.

By the way, it seems to be in conflict with `xserver-xorg*`, please be careful.

If you reboot, black screen. Enter ubuntu fix mode, use `aptitude` install `xserver-xorg*`, it will be ok.

```
sudo aptitude install xserver-xorg*
```